# Adding Custom Border Color Alpha to Attribute Inspector

Tags: swift3, alpha, uicolor, xcode8.2, cgcolor

I have a 2 part question. First I'd like to add border color alpha as a custom attribute, such as shown in this picture.

[image]

But the first thing I noticed is that to set the border color a `CGColor` has to be used instead of an `UIColor` and `CGColor.alpha` is read only.

So I tried using something like this, but it didn't really work.

```
@IBInspectable var borderAlpha: CGFloat {
    set {
        let borderCGColor = layer.borderColor
        var color = UIColor(cgColor: borderCGColor!)

        if (newValue < 0) {
            color = color.withAlphaComponent(0)
            layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        } else if (newValue > 1) {
            color = color.withAlphaComponent(1)
            layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        } else {
            color = color.withAlphaComponent(newValue)
            layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        }
    }
    get {
        return layer.borderColor!.alpha
    }
}
```

I do get this in the User Defined Runtime Attributes, but it doesn't take affect.

[image]

My guess is its because all the User Defined Runtime Attributes are called after the actual function that is being use, whereas mine isn't a real function, more of a custom function to get to what I want.
I also know that you can select alpha with the color selector, but for what I'm doing it'd be nice if they were separate.

Finally, as the 2nd question, on arrows that increase or decrease the values, it jumps by one, but on Xcode's alpha box it only jumps by 0.05 and can't go lower than 0 or higher than 1. How can I add this sort of functionality to my User Defined Runtime Attributes?

***EDIT***
Here is the full extension code I have for UIView that is working for everything except the border alpha.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable extension UIView {

@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
    set {
        layer.borderColor = newValue!.cgColor
    }
    get {
        if let color = self.layer.borderColor {
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderAlpha: CGFloat {
    set {
        let borderCGColor = layer.borderColor
        var color = UIColor(cgColor: borderCGColor!)

        if (newValue < 0) {
            color = color.withAlphaComponent(0)
            layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        } else if (newValue > 1) {
            color = color.withAlphaComponent(1)
            layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        } else {
            color = color.withAlphaComponent(newValue)
            layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        }
    }
    get {
        return layer.borderColor!.alpha
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
    set {
        layer.borderWidth = newValue
    }
    get {
        return layer.borderWidth
    }
}

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        clipsToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? {
    set {
        layer.shadowColor = newValue!.cgColor
    }
    get {
        if let color = self.layer.shadowColor {
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGSize {
    set {
        layer.shadowOffset = newValue
    }
    get {
        return layer.shadowOffset
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
    set {
        layer.shadowRadius = newValue
    }
    get {
        return layer.shadowRadius
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
    set {
        if (newValue < 0) {
            layer.shadowOpacity = 0
        } else if (newValue > 1) {
            layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        } else {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
    }
    get {
        return layer.shadowOpacity
    }
}
}
```

Comment: None of your key paths can work, because you forgot to include `layer` in the key path. Similarly, a view has no corner radius, border color, border width, or border alpha; to write any of these as an inspectable, you would need a setter for _every one of them_, to talk to the view's `layer`.

Comment: Oh, I've actually got all of those working. Sorry I'll include the full code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is that there is probably a fundamental uncertainty with regard to your `borderColor` and `borderAlpha` as to *which will be evaluated first.* Nothing is known or guaranteed about this, so if it happens that `borderAlpha` is set and then `borderColor`, `borderAlpha` will not be magically re-evaluated. In effect the mutual dependency here introduces an indeterminacy which may account for the difference in our experiences. It might be better, therefore, just to set the alpha as part of the color.

We can guess that this might be right, because your `borderAlpha` works fine for me:

[image]

We can guess, since it doesn't work for you, that this difference is mere chance; I was just lucky in that my `borderAlpha` was evidently evaluated after my `borderColor`, but we presumably cannot count on that.

By the way, I got your shadow attributes working as well:

[image]

You must have noticed that they were not working, surely? That is because of this line:

```
clipsToBounds = newValue > 0
```

Again, this can come along at any time and set your `clipsToBounds` to `false`, thus cutting off the shadow. (Or maybe they *were* working for you, and again this was just a matter of luck as to the order in which things were evaluated; the mutual dependency here is that `clipsToBounds` is set in `cornerRadius` but affects the shadow.

In short, what I think we learn here is that you need to keep these properties orthogonal to one another (independent).

Comment: Interesting. I had seen other code (not including the border alpha) that suggested using a class, I just wasn't sure how that would affect my objects. Because most of them inherit from a UIView, they all seem to get the code I added. I just wasn't sure what would happen to a UILabel if I changed its class to a custom class that was built off of UIView... would I need to make a separate class for each object to use it then?

Comment: By the way, there's a flaw in your code; you need to delete this line: `clipsToBounds = newValue > 0` It is preventing your shadow code from working.

Comment: "Finally, as the 2nd question, on arrows that increase or decrease the values, it jumps by one, but on Xcode's alpha box it only jumps by 0.05 and can't go lower than 0 or higher than 1. How can I add this sort of functionality to my User Defined Runtime Attributes?" I'm pretty sure there's no way. This would make a great feature request to Apple.

Comment: Oh, one more thought in regard to your original question. Isn't there a fundamental uncertainty with regard to your `borderColor` and `borderAlpha` as to _which will be evaluated first_? Nothing is known or guaranteed about this, so if it happens that `borderAlpha` is set and then `borderColor`, `borderAlpha` will not be magically re-evaluated. In effect the mutual dependency here introduces an indeterminacy which may account for the difference in our experiences. It might be better, therefore, just to set the alpha as part of the color.

Comment: That was actually something I had thought about too, I think you are probably right, better to do it in the color selector.

Comment: I'd better add that to my answer.

Comment: Okay, totally revamped my answer to incorporate some of the comments, and dropping the stuff about the extension.